# Is it possible to use classical Java synchronization to combine transients and reducers in Clojure?

Tags: java, concurrency, clojure

To optimize our implementation of the standard Clojure *frequencies* function

```
(defn my_frequencies_1 [coll]
  (reduce (fn [counts x]
            (assoc counts x (inc (get counts x 0))))
          {} coll))
```

we can use transients

```
(defn my_frequencies_2 [coll]
  (persistent!
    (reduce (fn [counts x]
              (assoc! counts x (inc (get counts x 0))))
            (transient {}) coll)))
```

or reducers.

```
(defn my_frequencies_3 [coll]
  (r/fold
    (fn combinef
      ([] {})
      ([coll1 coll2] (merge-with + coll1 coll2)))
    (fn reducef [coll x]
      (assoc coll x (inc (get coll x 0))))
  coll))
```

But if we try to use both mechanics

```
(defn my_frequencies_4 [coll]
  (persistent!
    (r/fold
      (fn combinef
        ([] (transient {}))
        ([coll1 coll2] (transient
                         (merge-with
                           +
                           (persistent! coll1)
                           (persistent! coll2)))))
      (fn reducef [coll x]
        (assoc! coll x (inc (get coll x 0))))
      coll)))

(with-out-str (time (do (my_frequencies_4 data) nil)))
```

we have a problem.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: null
              (Unknown Source) sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance
              (Unknown Source) sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance
              (Unknown Source) java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance
              (Unknown Source) java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException
              (Unknown Source) java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportResult
              (Unknown Source) java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join
              (Unknown Source) java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.invoke
               reducers.clj:49 clojure.core.reducers/fjinvoke
              reducers.clj:336 clojure.core.reducers/foldvec
              reducers.clj:357 clojure.core.reducers/eval10225[fn]
               reducers.clj:81 clojure.core.reducers/eval10096[fn]
               reducers.clj:98 clojure.core.reducers/fold
               reducers.clj:96 clojure.core.reducers/fold
    M:\clojure\reducers.clj:63 user/my-frequencies-4
    M:\clojure\reducers.clj:79 user/eval10803
```

I think that this is because only one thread at time had the right to work on the mutable data structure which is the transient map. Is it possible to use classical Java synchronization primitives in the last Clojure code to evade this problem?

Comment: As I understand it, the whole point of reducers is to allow parallel reduction and the whole point of transients is to provide fast mutable construction in a single threaded environment. Hacking around that to use transients in a concurrent context is definitely going against their design and doing so would be entering a world of dragons...